# how to get odd position inside a number camp

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get all odd position in a select statement.

Example:

```
EMPNO      ENAME             SAL         RN
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
7369       SMITH             800          1
```

i want to take all odd position of EMPNO

```
Output:

76
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_CHAR(EMPNO),'(.).', '\1') EMPNO_UPDATED from emptbl;
```

**Illustration (Oracle DB)**

```
-- Table DDL
create table emptbl
(
  EMPNO int,
  EMPNAME varchar2(100),
  SAL int,
  RN int
);

-- Populate table
insert into emptbl values(7369,'SMITH',800,1);
insert into emptbl values(123456789,'TOM',900,2);

-- Query table to get odd position numbers from EMPNO column
select REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_CHAR(EMPNO),'(.).', '\1') EMPNO_UPDATED from emptbl;
EMPNO_UPDATED
76
13579
```

Comment: thanks you, it was very useful!